# Better way to print different error message base on different if condition in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I wonder is there a better way to do the following?

```
if promo_code.present?
    if promo_code.active?(self)
      if !promo_code.expired?(self)
        if promo_code.applicable?(self)
          current_customer.promo_transactions.create!(promo_code: promo_code, order_id: id)
        else
          return false
        end
      else
        errors.add(:promo_code, message: 'Sorry! This code has expired')
        return false
      end
    else
      errors.add(:promo_code, message: 'Sorry! This code cannot be used at this time.')
      return false
    end
  else
    errors.add(:promo_code, message: 'Sorry! The code does not exist. Check for typos')
    return false
  end
```

if any of the conditions fail, I need to return false and a specific error message. The way I have looks pretty dumb and wonder is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
if !promo_code.present?(self)
  errors.add(:promo_code, message: 'Sorry! The code does not exist. Check for typos') 
elsif !promo_code.active?(self)
  errors.add(:promo_code, message: 'Sorry! This code cannot be used at this time.')
elsif promo_code.expired?(self) 
  errors.add(:promo_code, message: 'Sorry! This code has expired')
elsif promo_code.applicable?(self)
  current_customer.promo_transactions.create!(promo_code: promo_code, order_id: id)
else
  false
end
```

Or you could use inline conditions

```
errors.add(:promo_code, message: 'Sorry! The code does not exist. Check for typos') unless promo_code.present?(self)
errors.add(:promo_code, message: 'Sorry! This code cannot be used at this time.') unless promo_code.active?(self)
errors.add(:promo_code, message: 'Sorry! This code has expired') if promo_code.expired?(self) 
current_customer.promo_transactions.create!(promo_code: promo_code, order_id: id) if promo_code.applicable?(self)
false
```

take yer pick